# Swift problem when adding annotations with regex to pdf page

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-pdfkit

I want to search for a regex in a pdf, and add annotations to it according, using the results from the regex. I have built a simple function that does this. As the amazing community  (really amazing people who used their time helping me) posted I can I can use the *decomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping* to search for the desired expression correctly in the pdf, but afterwards when I perform a pdf selection to find the bounds of it, I encounter a difference. I send you my code and some pictures.

```
func performRegex(regex:String, on pdfPage:PDFPage)  {
    guard let pdfString = pdfPage.string?.precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping else { return }
    guard let safeRegex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: .caseInsensitive) else { return }
    let results = safeRegex.matches(in: pdfString, options: .withoutAnchoringBounds, range: NSRange(pdfString.startIndex..., in: pdfString))
    pdfPage.annotations.forEach { pdfPage.removeAnnotation($0)}
    results.forEach { result in
        let bbox = pdfPage.selection(for: result.range)?.bounds(for: pdfPage)
        let annotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: bbox!, forType: .highlight, withProperties: nil)
        annotation.color = .yellow
        annotation.contents = String(pdfString[Range(result.range, in:pdfString)!])
        pdfPage.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I do this and enter this expression [0-9] all my results are shifted:
[image: shifted results]

While if I don't use precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping, all my results are not shifted but I will encounter an error when I get a special character.
[image: not shifted results]

The problem (I suspect) is in this line of code.

```
let bbox = pdfPage.selection(for: result.range)?.bounds(for: pdfPage)
```

But I don't know any work arround for it.

Please if anyone can give me some help!

Thanks a lot

Comment: The issue is that you are using the decomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping range. You will need to find a way to convert that range.

Comment: Is there a way to replace the pdf original string with the decomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping string? I think it would be the simplest solution.

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes! I understand that is the problem, however I cannot change the string of the pdf, that would mean change the structure of the pdf. That solution I believe is not available.

Comment: I saw that string and attributed string properties are get only

Comment: So what do you suggest?

Comment: The only alternative I can imagine now is to use the original string and fix the malformed ranges.

Comment: You suggest retire the nil with something like compactmap?

Comment: check my post below

Comment: Ok, let me try it

Comment: I don't know, I should append the new string from the bad range to a string in case the result contains a bad range, no?

Comment: Did you understand what I am doing in my code?  I am concatenating the ranges that are not valid

Comment: Yes! Ahhh, when you  badrange!.length += 1

Comment: I haven't tried with other regex so It might not work as expected. If it doesn't let me know  so I can fix the code.

Comment: I'm trying with the pdf

Comment: I have tried other regex situations and it did work for me. I will try some other edge cases.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it ommits it". You need to get the range from two places

Comment: I will try to make it return an array with all ranges validated

Comment: My mistake, I don't fully understand your code, it works perfectlly but I cannot add the bad range to the selection

Comment: Why not? I don't understand. The range is built using the original string. let me edit my answer. I will simplify it

Comment: I don't know, my code only adds the good range, give me a second

Comment: So you need an array of `NSRange`s? No need to convert to `String.Range`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only alternative I can think right now is to use the original string and fix the malformed ranges. Try like this:

```
var str = """
circular para poder realizar sus tareas laborales correspondientes a las actividades de comercialización de alimentos
"""
do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: ".", options: .caseInsensitive)
    let results = regex.matches(in: str, options: .withoutAnchoringBounds, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: str.utf16.count))
    var badrange: NSRange?
    results.forEach { result in
        guard let range = Range(result.range, in: str) else {
            if badrange != nil {
                badrange!.length += 1
                if let range = Range(badrange!, in: str) {
                    let newStr = str[range]
                    print(newStr)
                }
            } else {
                badrange = result.range
            }
            return
        }
        let newStr = str[range]
        print(newStr)
        badrange = nil
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```